# html instead of google maps marker image

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

Is it possible to display HTML instead of an image as a Google Maps Marker ?

What is the best way to do so?
I imagine that something like an invisible marker and a custom info-window might play a role in achieving this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `OverlayView` class to create custom overlays with html elements - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays

Simple example - http://jsfiddle.net/BCr2B/

Comment: the css gets all messed up :s
I'm trying to create this marker: http://jsfiddle.net/BW3ca/9/

Comment: please post on fiddle how you add it on the map and what's the problem exactly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BCr2B/1/ the fiddle works perfect, but for some reason when I rewrite it the css gets messed up :s

Comment: exactly, for me to.
But when I copy everything to a blank document the css gets all weird, color stays the same but the positioning gets all crazy :p

Comment: oh i see, that's because fiddle uses normalized css by default if you uncheck it from the options on the left it gets messed up, so the problem only in your css now :)

Comment: can the overlay be draggable?

Comment: yes it can, example using jqueryUI to make it draggable -  http://jsfiddle.net/BCr2B/7/. Basically, you'll need to block propagation of map mouse events on that overlay so you can attach your own.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this out:  https://github.com/jonyt/gmaps-div-overlay

> DivOverlay is a very simple container for HTML to be shown over a
>   Google Map at any position. All it does is calculate margins from the
>   map bounds so its entire contents are within the map. Take a look at
>   the demo. The constructor takes 3 arguments: the HTML container, the
>   map to attach to and the position of the overlay. DivOverlay has only
>   two functions: show() and hide(). Should be self-explanatory.